# Load Xdocument with RSS feed in MVVM app

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, linq-to-xml

I am learning MVVM & Linq to xml by converting a simple wpf RSS app. Originally, I used XmlDataProvider to load local xml files or RSS urls. I am now using the code below which works fine loading local xml files, but throws the "FileNotFoundException" when its a url. During debugging I see the correct url address in (string RSS_URL), yet the file is not found. My initial searching led me to Webclient & HttpWebRequest, but I haven't had any success with them. Am I on the right track? Any code or tutorial links available?

```
public static List<RSSItem> Load(string RSS_URL)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(RSS_URL))
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Datasource file could not be found", RSS_URL);
        }

        var rssfiles = XDocument.Load(RSS_URL).Descendants("item").Select(
            x => new RSSItem(
                (string)x.Element("title"),
                (string)x.Element("link"),
                (string)x.Element("description"))); 

        return rssfiles.ToList();
    }
```

Thank You

Comment: I would recommend using [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) instead, it's better integrated into the binding system.

Comment: @H.B. What do you mean by "better integrated into the binding system"?

Comment: @DanEsparza: See the [`Binding.XPath` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.xpath.aspx), you can only use it with the `XmlDocument` family.

Comment: @H.B. Ah -- I see the question was specific to WPF.  That makes more sense.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XDocument.Load() will accept URLs without any problem. The issue in your code is that you're using File.Exists() to determine whether or not he URL is valid. File.Exists() only accepts a filesystem path, not a uri.

Quick piece of additional info: the Load() method relies on an underlying XmlReader and a call to Create(). If the resource (the URL in this case) doesn't exist, a WebException will be thrown indicating that the resource doesn't exist.

XDocument.Load info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181.aspx

XmlReader.Create info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k674bf.aspx

Comment: Awesome - How do you know such things! I don't know how I would have ever figured that out without your help. Works great. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The `XDocument.Load` overload you are using is specifically for loading from a file. You would have to download from the RSS feed to get the XML data locally. Look at the MSDN document [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load.aspx) for alternatives such as reading from a stream, which might be better suited to what you need.